# how to pass the result of an JavaScript function (canPlayType) to an HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I need to send videos to client sites but I do not want to send duplicates due to different codecs).

I am having lots of problems getting the results of a jscript function into a $variable. Due to the complexity of my retrieval SELECT I am unable to use DISTINCT, I need to include the extension.

I have spent days on this downloading "examples" that I am unable to get to work. Below is the latest created from two examples Detecting HTML5 videos and How to pass jscript variables.

```
    <script>
    function playsvideo() {
        return supports_video();
    }
    function supports_h264() {
        var v = document.createElement("video");
        return v.canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"');
    }
    function supports_ogg() {
        var v = document.createElement("video");
        return v.canPlayType('video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"');
    }
    function supports_webm() {
        var v = document.createElement("video");
        return v.canPlayType('video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"');
    }
    <?php
    if(playsvideo()) {
        if(supports_ogg()?true:false)  {$ext='ogv';}
        else if(supports_webm()?true:false) {$ext='webm';}
        else if(supports_h264()?true:false) {$ext='mp4';}
        else {$ext='flash';}
    }
    ?>
    </script>
```

The web pages works if I pass a constant to MYSQL but with the above code as the last items in my HEAD section, the web page hangs with just a blank page (background color is set). I have also tried with just the php stripped down to one line:

```
if(paysvideo()) {$ext='ogv';} // still hangs
```

Comment: playsvideo() is a JS function, you can't reference it in PHP...

Comment: So you want to detect browser support and based on that get your video from a PHP query to MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I used Modernizr http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html and a hidden field [How do I use Javascript to change value of a hidden input depending on status of a checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267758/how-do-i-use-javascript-to-change-value-of-a-hidden-input-depending-on-status-of)

```
    <input id="myvideoext"type="hidden" name="myvideoext"   value="fallback">

if (Modernizr.video) {
  if (Modernizr.video.ogg) {
        document.getElementById('myvideoext').value="ogv";
  } else if (Modernizr.video.webm) {
    document.getElementById('myvideoext').value="webm";
  } else if (Modernizr.video.h264){
    document.getElementById('myvideoext').value="mp4";
  }
}
```