# Take innerHTML value with post method PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to take the innerHTML value of a label element in a form with method post and show it to another PHP page. But i have only work with that with textboxes, as an example in a login form. Any ideas??

```
<div id="menu" class="menu">
        <label class="" ></label>
        <label id="minutes">00</label>
        <label>:</label>
        <label id="seconds">00</label>
        <label id="" style="margin-left: 30px"></label>
        <label id="accuracyLetter" style="position:relative;">100%</label>
        <label id="" style="margin-left: 30px"></label>
        <label id="totalAccuracy">100%</label>
   </div>
```

Comment: Please post example code

Comment: You can't post the value of a label.

Comment: You can't pass the value of a label using a form and only PHP.

Comment: Use hidden element near label!

Comment: but how i will do not to pass a static value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="label-value" value="innerHTML"/>
```

This will add `label-value` to the `post` hash.

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp)

Comment: yes but i dont want to have a static value to be posting.

Comment: The set it with javascript. Why are you changing the label's value?

Comment: because in the label i am showing a result, which is going to be different in every post

Comment: How is that value set?, PHP?

Comment: no, i change in a JS function

Comment: Then set the value of the input field at the same time.

Comment: Is is right to set the value with .value option? It shows no result!

Comment: [How do I use Javascript to change value of a hidden input depending on status of a checkbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267758/how-do-i-use-javascript-to-change-value-of-a-hidden-input-depending-on-status-of)

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this after label

```
<input type='hidden' name='postname' value='labelvalue'/>
```

In php

```
<?php
$labelname = $_POST['postname'];
echo $labelname;
?>
```

that's it !

Comment: Me only add first comment to you brother! And Give hint also.

Comment: where you have labelvalue, what i will put? sorry i am little confused!

Comment: In the label i'll have a result, which is going to change in every submit. So i can not have a static value

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to post "Some Name" to your php script?

```
<form action="script.php">
    <label for="name">
        Some Name
    </label>

    <input id="name" name="name">
</form>
```

If so you will need to add it as a hidden input:

Option 1: Using javascript

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('form').on('submit', function () {
            var labelText = $(this).find('label').text();
            $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="label-text" value="' + labelText + '">');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Option 2:

Echo it together with the input field in your php.

```
<label>Some text</label>
<input type="hidden" name="label-text" value="Some text">
```

Comment: That pure JavaScript right there...