# Sending innerhtml to server script by form post action fails

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post

I am very new to html. I am trying to send the content of the page when it loads to a http server by post action. On the other end I just get the name of the object value of which I thought I am accessing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <body>
     <form action="http://localhost:7788" method="POST">
         <input type="text" name="firstname" value=innerHTML /><br />
         <input type="hidden" name="label-value" value="innerHTML"/>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form> 
   </body>
</html>
```

On the server side :

```
  for item in form.list:
            logging.warning(item)
        print "%s=%s" % (item.name, item.value)
```

I get this only:

```
WARNING:root:======= POST VALUES =======
WARNING:root:MiniFieldStorage('firstname', 'hhh')
firstname=hhh
WARNING:root:MiniFieldStorage('label-value', 'innerHTML')
label-value=innerHTML
WARNING:root:
```

I was using this as help: [Take innerHTML value with post method PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20352579/take-innerhtml-value-with-post-method-php)

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

The below code works in sending the html code but the problem is that this runs without users choice and then redirects the page to somewhere else.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script>

function post(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", document.body.innerHTML);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}

post('http://localhost:8002', {name: 'html'});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get this out put which is great:

```
    Serving at: http://localhost:8002
WARNING:root:======= POST STARTED =======
WARNING:root:======= POST VALUES =======
name=
 <form id="form" action="http://localhost:7777" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="firstname" value="innerHTML"><br>
     <input type="hidden" name="label-value" value="innerHTML">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="one">
  </form> 

<script>

function post(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", document.body.innerHTML);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}

post('http://localhost:8002', {name: 'html'});
</script>
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2016 16:15:10] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 0):

The file (http://localhost:7788) that accepts your POST request, will accept string, you can view this string by running the code below:

```
from flask import request
print request.data
```

I hope it helps you.

**BUT!**

If you need to send content of the page, you need to do something like this:

Edit HTML by:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <body>
 <form action="http://localhost:7788" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="firstname" value=innerHTML /><br />
     <input type="hidden" name="label-value" value="innerHTML"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="one" />
  </form> 

<script>
document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("content", document.body.innerHTML);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if (4 == this.readyState) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
};
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:7788", true);
xhr.send(formData);
return false;
},false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, when you press Submit button, POST will be sent to your server with content of the page.

Comment: Thanks man but when I copied this just as is into the file and loaded the html after clicking on the button nothing happens on either side

Comment: Try to change your .py file with code below:

from flask import Flask, request

and link to Flask documentation http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/

Comment: Link to the Runnable:

http://code.runnable.com/UpYA9FUz6V5XAAAN/get-querystring-and-form-data-from-request-in-flask-for-python

"form data from request" is what you need

Comment: You can view response, just open your browser inspector console (Ex. in mozilla: right click -> inspect element -> console). Then click Submit and see what you got. And also check your python logging.